# Django runserver not serving some static files

Tags: django, python-3.x

My local testing server for Django v1.8.2 on Windows 8.1 is only serving certain static files. Others are giving a 404 error.

```
#urls.py - excerpt
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index)
] + staticfiles_urlpatterns()

#settings.py - excerpt
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main',
    'users'
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

As far as I can tell the development server is configured to serve static files. When running `runserver` I get no warnings, and my code displays no syntax errors (`import` statements do exist and so forth). I did for testing purposes run `collectstatic` before starting the server just to be sure at least once.

My view template is:

```
{%  load staticfiles %}
<img src="{%  static 'main/img/ComingSoon.jpg' %}" alt="Coming Soon">
```

The link generated is `/static/main/img/ComingSoon.jpg` which looks correct, the file does exist in that location. What perplexes me is that this directory produces a `404` error, but other static files are served. The directory hierarchy is:

```
static/
  admin/
    css/
      ..
    js/
      ..
    img/
      ..
  main/
    img/
      ComingSoon.jpg
```

The URL `localhost:8000/static/admin/img/` gives an expected message about indexes being not allowed. However, `localhost:8000/static/main/img/` reports `\main\img\` cannot be found. Both are `404` statuses. Images within `static/admin/img/` do display correctly with the same links as what is giving an error. The Administration site for Django does display correctly.

Why would one directory within `static/` not be indexed or accessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_URL) regarding `static/`:

> This should be an initially empty destination directory for collecting
>   your static files from their permanent locations into one directory
>   for ease of deployment; it is not a place to store your static files
>   permanently. You should do that in directories that will be found by
>   staticfiles’s finders, which by default, are 'static/' app
>   sub-directories and any directories you include in STATICFILES_DIRS).

I moved the files to another directory such as:

```
myApp/
  main/
    static/
      main/
        img/
          ..
  static/
    ..
```

After running `collectstatic` I noticed the script created the subdirectories in `myApp/static/` as expected and it must have generated the URLs needed because it now properly serves the files.